# How many combinations of $5$ balls for which the product of the numbers on the balls are odd are there?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $8$ blue balls numbered from $1-8$, and $8$ red balls numbered from $1-8$.

How many combinations of $5$ balls for which the product of the numbers on the balls are odd are there?

I got the answer $\binom{8}{5}$; $8$ odd numbers and you choose $5$ of them.

Comment: Your solution is basically correct.  I would say that there are eight balls with odd numbers and you choose five of them.

Answer (score 0):

When the product of $n$ numbers is odd it means that all numbers are odd. We have 8 odd numbers (and 8 even), and we select 5 of them. That is $${8\choose 5}$$